# Quantization of charge from the path integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, charge, group-theory, topology, noethers-theorem

Consider a complex scalar field, with the usual Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L} = | \partial_{\mu} \phi|^2 - V(|\phi|^2).
$$
This theory has a $U(1)$ symmetry, $\phi \to e^{i \alpha} \phi$, and the resulting Noether current is
$$
j_{\mu} = i (\phi^* \partial_{\mu} \phi - \phi \partial_{\mu} \phi^*).
$$
The associated charge is $$Q = \int d^d x j^0.$$ If one employs canonical quantization, writing $\phi$ in terms of two sets of creation/annihilation operators, one finds
$$
Q = \int \frac{d^d p}{(2\pi)^d} (a^{\dagger}_p a_p - b^{\dagger}_p b_p).
$$
As a result, it is clear that the spectrum of $Q$ is precisely the integers, $\mathbb{Z}$.

Of course, one does not need to diagonalize $Q$ in terms of ladder operators to come to this conclusion. Essentially by definition, or by using the real-space CCR, one finds that $Q$ generates $U(1)$ transformations in the following way:
$$
e^{-i\alpha Q} \phi(x) e^{i\alpha Q} = e^{i \alpha} \phi(x).
$$
Since rotations by $\alpha = 2\pi$ leave $\phi(x)$ invariant, we must have $Q \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is to say, the integer quantization of $Q$ is closely related to the fact that the symmetry group is compact.

All of the above is from the operator formalism. Here is the question: *is there any obvious way to see that the Noether charge $Q$ should be quantized strictly within the path integral representation?* What I'm imagining is that there may be some *topological* restriction on $Q$ which causes it to take integer values in all field configurations. But I have no idea how this can come about here.

Comment: Hi Zach: What prevents you from applying essentially the same argument for the path integral by assuming that the field transforms in some group representation?

Comment: Well, it's hard for me to make sense of the expression $e^{-i \alpha Q} \phi(x) e^{i \alpha Q}$ in the path integral; this is an operator equation, and it makes most sense to me in terms of the commutation relations between $Q$ and $\phi$. I believe the infinitesimal version of this equation is essentially the Ward identity, which makes perfect sense to me within the path integral. But it seems as though the finite transformation is crucial for seeing that $Q$ is quantized (in the infinitesimal version, I don't see how we can distinguish a $U(1)$ symmetry and an $\mathbb{R}$ symmetry).

Comment: Presumably, to make sense of this expression inside a path integral, I should consider the time-ordered expression $e^{-i \alpha Q(t^+)} \phi(t,\vec{x}) e^{i \alpha Q(t^-)}$, where $t^{\pm} = t \pm \varepsilon$. Is it possible to then "exponentiate" the Ward identity to obtain the desired transformation law?

Comment: I suppose the part that really throws me for a loop is this: I understand perfectly well what it means for the *operator* $\hat{Q}$ to be quantized to the integers: it has some eigenspectrum, and all of its eigenvalues are integers. But when I write the Noether expression for $Q$ in terms of fields which are integrated in the path integral, it's not at all clear that this expression should be quantized in any way.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me rewrite the conserved current as a [one-form](https://www.wikipedia.com/en/Differential_form), $j = j_\mu \mathrm{d}{x^\mu}$. This allows me to rewrite the charge as
$$Q[\Sigma] = \int_\Sigma \star j,\tag{1}$$
where $\Sigma$ is *any* closed spacelike codimension-1 submanifold of the manifold where your theory is defined and $\star$ is the [Hodge-star operator](https://www.wikipedia.com/en/Hodge_star). Taking $\Sigma$ to be the whole space reduces to the usual equation
$$Q = \int_\text{space} \mathrm{d}^{D-1}x\ j_0.$$

Now, what's the benefit of (1)? You see, codimension-1 stuff can surround local operators/field configurations and this is how you measure their charge. Essentially this is the content of Gauss law in electrodynamics.

So now you can calculate a path integral like
$$\left<\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha Q[\Sigma]}\phi(x)\cdots\right> = \int \mathrm{D}\phi\  \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}S}\ \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha Q[\Sigma]}\phi(x)\cdots,$$
where $\Sigma$ tightly surrounds $x$, and the rest of the insertions (the $\cdots$) are far from $x$. But this is simply measuring the charge of $\phi$! Therefore
$$\left<\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha Q[\Sigma]}\phi(x)\cdots\right> = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha}\left<\phi(x)\cdots\right>$$
and you can now run the rest of your argument leading to quantisation of the charge.

Comment: I don’t see how this addresses the question. In particular, I don’t understand how the final equation logically follows from the preceding discussion. But more importantly, what does it mean for $Q[\Sigma]$ to be quantized in the path integral? It’s a functional of the field $\phi$ which is integrated over in the path integral, not an operator, so it’s hard to see what it even means for it to be quantized without referring back to the operator formalism.